# jQuery / CSS Zoom div contents only

Tags: jquery, css

I want to zoom on the contents of a div, but I want the div to maintain position and height/width regardless of it's zoom level.

I made this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fD7L7/5/

The thing is, the div I want to zoom in/out on acts as a container for a number of draggables.

Halp?

```
var currZoom = 1;

$(".zoomIn").click(function(){
    currZoom+=0.1;
    $('.board').css(
    {
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : '45px',
        'left' : '20px',
        'height' : $(window).height()-65,
        'width' : $(window).width()-40,
        'zoom' : currZoom
    });
});

$(".zoomOff").click(function()
{
    currZoom=1;
    $(".board").css(
    {
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : '45px',
        'left' : '20px',
        'height' : $(window).height()-65,
        'width' : $(window).width()-40,
        'zoom' : currZoom
    });
});

$(".zoomOut").click(function()
{
    currZoom-=0.1;
    $('.board').css(
    {
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : '45px',
        'left' : '20px',
        'height' : $(window).height()-65,
        'width' : $(window).width()-40,
        'zoom' : currZoom
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this plugin? http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see how it would help me though...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vaFQ9/

```
<div class='outboard'>
    <div class="board">
        <div class="draggable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An absolutely-positioned container div ('.outboard'), and a relatively-positioned inner div ('.board').  The container div's overflow properties (scroll, in this example) create the appearance of a fixed-size container, the contents of which zoom in and out.

```
.outboard
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 45px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.board
{
    background-color: #334433; /* not actually relevant */
}
```

The .outboard element is where you specify the apparent position/block properties on the page, and the .board element starts out as an identically-sized div (you may need to fiddle around with padding and margins to make sure they're flush to begin with.

I've butchered your original code a bit in the jsfiddle, but hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: thanks... but the draggables are still limited by the .board div... I suppose I should've specified that in the question...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, then.  You want the child elements of the board div to be zoomable, and retain their zoomed state when removed from the board div?

Comment: Okay. The board div is set up to have a certain size (height, width and relative position), depending on client window size.
I want the board div to retain size etc, while the child elements are zoomed in or out, so the container (board div) will remain static in it's capacity as container. Picture a bulletin board where you can zoom in or out on it's contents - not the biard itself.